# Opening session via XDMCP to GDM

Tags: rhel, x11, session, gdm, xdmcp

I have a RHEL6 server which we connect via XDMCP. If I start xdm (`xdm &`) it works but the login screen is the old xdm simple login and not gdm. Our RHEL5 servers connect to gdm just fine. The problem is that GDM isn't running. When I try to launch GDM (`gdm &`) it gives me the following message:

```
** (gdm-binary:3229): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried using (gdm-binary &) and get the same message.

```
cat /etc/gdm/custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage
[daemon]
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
AllowRemoteRoot=true
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
[greeter]
IncludeAll=true
[chooser]
[debug]
```

In /etc/X11/xdm/Xaccess I have the following uncommented:
   `*                                       #any host can get a login window`

In /etc/X11/xdm/xdm-config I have tried commenting and uncommenting the following:
    `DisplayManager.requestPort:    0`

I've referenced several tutorials such as:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDM_XDMCP.html

http://kosala-linux.blogspot.com/2013/02/x-manager-configurations-for-rheloel.html

Comment: Why you dont' use gdm service?

Comment: Which service is that? There doesn't seem to be an init script in `/etc/init.d/`. There is a file called `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` but it doesn't appear to be a normal init script.

Comment: wow, do you compiled?

Comment: A gdm service doesn't appear when using ntsysv either so I don't think that's an option on RHEL6

Comment: Nope. It's a fresh RHEL6 install.

Comment: i invited to chat, please answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11012/discussion-between-jeight-and-mohsen-pahlevanzadeh)

Comment: Is `dbus-daemon --system` running (in the output of `ps fax`)?

Comment: No. It doesn't show there.

Comment: @Jeight: probably fixed by installing the `dbus` package and maybe issuing a `service messagebus restart`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. If you want to put your answer in I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning:

```
** (gdm-binary:3229): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

means that the system D-Bus message bus is not running. D-Bus provides message buses that programs can use to communicate with other programs: there is usually a system message bus, and a message bus per user session.

On RHEL, the system message bus is started by the `messagebus` init script, provided by the `dbus` package.

To start the system message bus you'll have to install the `dbus` package, and probably issue a `service messagebus restart`.